# show that $\lim_{n→\infty} f(x_n)$ exists.

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $A \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ and $f : A \longrightarrow  \Bbb{R}^m$ be a uniformly continuous function. If
${x_n}$ where $n\geq 1$   is a Cauchy sequence in $A$ then show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ exists.
If the domain be $\mathbb{R}$ then there is no problem to solve it but I need help here.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Pleas show us what you've tried, and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: SANDEEP, I see that you and "@Ity" share an internet address, and seem to have been upvoting each other's questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**$\;\;$ Show that the sequence $\,\{f(x_n)\}\;$ is Cauchy and hence converges, since $\,\mathbb{R}^m\,$ is complete.